# Slow SQL query when grouping by two columns with self join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, group-by

I have a table `rating` with slightly less than 300k rows and a SQL query:

```
  SELECT rt1.product_id as id1, rt2.product_id as id2, sum(1), sum(rt1.rate-rt2.rate) as sum 
FROM rating as rt1 
JOIN rating as rt2 ON rt1.user_id = rt2.user_id AND rt1.product_id != rt2.product_id 
group by rt1.product_id, rt2.product_id
LIMIT 1
```

The problem is.. it's really slow. It takes 36 secs to execute it with `limit 1`, while I need to execute it without limit.
As I figured out, slowdown it caused by `GROUP BY` part. It works fine while grouping by one column no matter from which table rt1 or rt2. 
I have also tried with indexes, I have created already indexes for user_id, product_id, rate and (user_id, product_id).

`EXPLAIN` doesn't tell much to me too.

```
 id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  rt1     ALL     PRIMARY,user_id,user_product    NULL    NULL    NULL    289700  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  rt2     ref     PRIMARY,user_id,user_product    user_id     4   mgrshop.rt1.user_id     30  Using where
```

I need this to execute just once to generate some data, so it's not important to achieve optimal time, but reasonable.

Any ideas?

Edit.

Full table schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rating` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `user_product` (`user_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `rate` (`rate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: post the full schema of both tables please.

Comment: it's just one table, but self joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I did it via temp table. 
First selected rows without grouping and put them into a table made just for it. I got over 11kk rows. Then I just grouped them from temp table and put into final table.

Then I also tried to do this without creating any other table and it also worked for me.

```
SELECT id1, id2, sum(count), sum(sum) 
FROM (SELECT rt1.product_id as id1, rt2.product_id as id2, 1 as count, rt1.rate - rt2.rate as sum 
        FROM rating as rt1 
        JOIN rating as rt2 ON rt1.user_id = rt2.user_id AND rt1.product_id != rt2.product_id) as temptab
GROUP BY id1, id2
```

And finally got about 19k rows.

Execution time: 35.8669
Not bad for my case of one-time data generating.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the join, specifically `AND rt1.product_id != rt2.product_id`. 
Lets say a user has rated 100 products, for that user, this query will generate 99,000 rows before it does the group by. For each of the 100 ratings, the table gets joined back to itself 99 times.

What is the question you are trying to answer with this query? Depending on that, there may be some more efficient approaches. Its just hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I wanna get avarage ( sum and count) difference between rating of every two products.

Comment: You may get better performance by aggreating the data twice in two seperate sub-queries and then comparing the results. Have a look at this SQL fiddle as an example. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9ad8c/4 
Note: I'm still unclear what the answer you are looking for is exactly "avarage ( sum and count) difference" doesn't mean anything ot me, but hope this will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I can't do this your way, because differences are counted for every user, for every 2 products that he rated. You missed user issue. I can see I didn't mentioned that in previous comment. Thought it is certain since it doesn't make any sense any other way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Declan_K mentioned about your cross-join result set that could be 100k rows before you know it, you could cut that down significantly by changing to just

rt1.product_id < rt2.product_id

instead of

rt1.product_id != rt2.product_id

Reason...  Since they are the same table/records, you will only need to cycle through them once for the RT1.product_ID.  With it being less than the highest, you'll already have the high as part of your compare.  As it stands, if you did (for a single user) have 5 products (1-5), you would be getting results of

```
(1,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)  (1,5)
(2,1)  (2,3)  (2,4)  (2,5)
(3,1)  (3,2)  (3,4)  (3,5)
(4,1)  (4,2)  (4,3)  (4,5)
(5,1)  (5,2)  (5,3)  (5,4)
```

By changing to LESS than, you'll eliminate the duplications such as 1,2 vs 2,1     1,3 vs 3,1

```
(1,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)  (1,5)
       (2,3)  (2,4)  (2,5)
              (3,4)  (3,5)
                     (4,5)
```

Just a bit of a  smaller result set, and this is with only 5 products for one person.

Comment: It doesn't solve computational complexity problem, just divide generated data by 2. Cartesian product of self join is still O(n^2) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not the easiest, but it should explain a little and speed up your query time.

When you join in MySQL, a temporary table is created. The more rows that are put into that temporary table, the more likely it is to go to disk. Disk is slow. The new temporary table has no indices. Querying without indices is slow.

The first line in your EXPLAIN statement is showing that the query will join first, creating a  whole bunch of rows, and sticking that into a temporary table, and grouping by product ids. The `key` column is empty, showing that it can't use a key.

My solution is to create another table. This other table will consist of all the relevant columns from the JOIN. You'll need a batch job to update the table in the background. This will lead to slightly stale data, but it will run much faster.

```
CREATE TABLE `rate_tmp` (
  userid ...,
  id1 ...,
  id2 ...,
  rate1 ...,
  rate2 ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, userid)
)
```

The order on the primary key is very important. Your query then looks like this:

```
SELECT userid, id1, id2, sum(1), sum(rate1-rate2) as sum
from rate_tmp
group by id1, id2;
```

It should run very fast at that point, because, while the table is still persisted to disk, MySQL will not have to write the data to disk at query time. It can also, and more importantly, use the pre-defined indices that you have on the temporary table.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, I've tried it, and it actually worked. But the query also mentioned in that answer works with similar performance.

Comment: What is the schema of the temp table? Did you insert on the fly into the temp table or with a background job?

Comment: My temp table looked just like the destination table. I was just not grouped, so it didn't have (product1_id, product2_id) primary key because it was not unique.

Comment: The primary key, including its order, was important because it added the key you needed to do the group by statement using an index. Using the new query and the new temporary table, paste the schema, the query, and the explain statement.